# Python-Django program working in Postman but not working on connecting to an iOS app

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a created a simple Python program, which will retrieve and add data to database based on the user input. I used **POST** method for this. The program is successfully working in Postman, but when I call the program from an iOS app using API call, the program is showing **500 error**. The errors are in **exception.py** and **base.py**. My program is given below

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def mg_grt(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        word = name.lower()
        greet = Greet.objects.filter(grett=word)
        if greet != 0:
            d = Resp(rsp=word)
            d.save()
            r_val = Resp.objects.all()
            rt = random.choice(r_val)
            return HttpResponse(rt)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Sorry...I didn't understand")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Bad Request")
```

The errors are:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 53, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/abijith/Test5/tgpi/views.py", line 21, in mg_grt
    name = request.POST['name']
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
MultiValueDictKeyError: "u'name'"
[31/Aug/2018 10:20:45] "POST /grt/ HTTP/1.1" 500 14099
```

Comment: seems like you are not sending `name` from the iOS app

Comment: Okay let me try it

Comment: If the `name` is a required field, you should return a 400 Bad Request HttpResponse as a best practice.

Comment: Can you try logging request.data before accessing name ?